# Cannot align text content of column to center

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want align the text inside a column to center, for do this I've created a resource:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroGridViewColumn}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

but I get

> Cannot Resolve the Resource "MetroGridViewColumn"

Note that: I need to align the text inside the column, not the header without lost Mahapp style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of the style is `MetroGridViewColumnHeader` and can be found in `Controls.ListView.xaml`.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.ListView.xaml" />
```

So your custom style should look like

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroGridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: @AgainMe That's right, cause it's for the GridViewColumnHeader. If you want change the cell content you must create your own CellTemplate for the GridViewColumn.